# Alt text when inserting image into RMarkdown with knitr::include_graphics?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When inserting an image into an RMarkdown doc that has `output: html_document`, we can use

````
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="A caption", out.width = '100%'}
knitr::include_graphics("path/to/image.png")
```
````

How can the image be given [alt text](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp)?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.rstudio.com/blog/knitr-fig-alt/

Comment: @franzbischoff very cool, looks like a new way to add an alt tag without needing to do both a) add fig.cap and b) set fig_caption: false. Much simpler now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After **knitr** v1.31 (Jan 27, 2021), you can use the chunk option `fig.alt` to provide the alt text.

Before **knitr** v1.31, you can use the chunk option `fig.cap` to generate the alt text. If you view the HTML source of the `.html` output file, you will see the `<img>` tag with the `alt` attribute.

```html
<img src="...base64..." alt="A caption" ... />
```

However, a side-effect of using `fig.cap` is that it will generate a figure caption, too. To disable the figure caption, you may turn it off in the output format, e.g.,

```
output:
  html_document:
    fig_caption: false
```

Comment: So it does! Is there a way to generate the alt text *without* `fig.cap` option? (i.e. for images that aren't captioned?)

Comment: Yes, `fig_caption: false` for `html_document`: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#figure-options

Comment: Hi Yihui, [@franzbischoff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482214/alt-text-when-inserting-image-into-rmarkdown-with-knitrinclude-graphics?noredirect=1#comment125263044_61482214) points out a possible new way of adding the alt tag.

Comment: @stevec Thanks for the reminder! I just updated the answer accordingly.